# Hover affect for two elements

Tags: html, css

i've got problem. I cant force the code to hover `h3`and `div` "underline" at the same time.

Thereis my code: https://jsfiddle.net/nac3570n/

As you can see hover's working but doesnt affect to underline at the same time, unless u'll move cursor on underline

Comment: Right, like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/StrubT/nac3570n/1/)?

Comment: Im so dumb, thanks :)

Comment: No problem, it happens to all of us... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this:

```
.underline:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

to this:

```
a:hover .underline {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Basically we move both `:hover` events to trigger on the same action. In this case, hovering over the parent `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/qmg6wbv5/1/

...fiddle doesn't use your exact styles, but you'll have an easier time using a pseudo element (`:after`) on the h3, I think. That way it naturally responds to hovering the h3.  Hope that gets you on the right track.